# MVC 5 DROPDOWN LIST BASED ON TABLE ID (PRIMARY KEY)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a job portal application, I have two model classes:

1. Vacancy
2. VacancyOption

`VacancyOption` has a foreign key to the `Vacancy` table, a `Vacancy` can have many job options based on the `VacancyId`.

[That's the table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1g3e.png)

I want on each row of my View html table to list available vacancy Options to dropdown corresponding List of value. below is my View image

[My View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kotNp.png)

Currently the dropdown is list all what I have in the `VacancyOption` table, but I want it to display only based `VacancyId`  which is also the table Id and also Id referenced by `VacancyOption` (`Vacancy_Id`) foreign key.